# assign max+1 to the unmatching record

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `dataframe` like provided below:

```
+-------+--------------+----+-------------+
|recType|registerNumber|mnId|     sequence|
+-------+--------------+----+-------------+
|     01|      13578000|   0|            1|
|     11|      13578000|   1|            1|
|     13|      13578000|   2|            1|
|     14|      13578000|   3|            1|
|     14|      13578000|   4|            1|
|     01|      11121000|   5|            2|
|     11|      11121000|   6|            2|
|     13|      11121000|   7|            2|
|     14|      11121000|   8|            2|
|     01|      OC387000|   9|            3|
|     11|      OC387000|  10|            3|
|     13|      OC387000|  11|            3|
|     01|      11121000|  12|            4|
|     11|      11121000|  13|            4|
|     13|      11121000|  14|            4|
|     14|      11121000|  15|            4|
|     11|      OC321000|  16|            4|
|     13|      OC321000|  17|            4|
|     01|      OC322000|  18|            5|
|     11|      OC322000|  19|            5|
|     13|      OC322000|  20|            5|
|     11|      SO352000|  21|            5|
|     13|      SO352000|  22|            5|
+-------+--------------+----+-------------+
```

If you notice here, `sequence` 4 and 5 has more than one `registerNumber`. This is happening because, some record sets do not have `recType` `01`. A record set usually starts with `recType` `01`.

`registerNumber` starting with `OC3`, `SO3` may or may not have `recType` `01`.  So, the `sequence` column considers them part of previous record set.

I want to make sure that if two `registerNumbers` comes under a same `sequence` and the `registerNumber` starts with `OC3` or `SO3`. A new `Sequence` value should be assigned to them, which should be `max(sequence)+1`.

So, the resultant `dataframe` should look as below:

```
+-------+--------------+----+-------------+
|recType|registerNumber|mnId|     sequence|
+-------+--------------+----+-------------+
|     01|      13578000|   0|            1|
|     11|      13578000|   1|            1|
|     13|      13578000|   2|            1|
|     14|      13578000|   3|            1|
|     14|      13578000|   4|            1|
|     01|      11121000|   5|            2|
|     11|      11121000|   6|            2|
|     13|      11121000|   7|            2|
|     14|      11121000|   8|            2|
|     01|      OC387000|   9|            3|
|     11|      OC387000|  10|            3|
|     13|      OC387000|  11|            3|
|     01|      11121000|  12|            4|
|     11|      11121000|  13|            4|
|     13|      11121000|  14|            4|
|     14|      11121000|  15|            4|
|     11|      OC321000|  16|            6|
|     13|      OC321000|  17|            6|
|     01|      OC322000|  18|            5|
|     11|      OC322000|  19|            5|
|     13|      OC322000|  20|            5|
|     11|      SO352000|  21|            7|
|     13|      SO352000|  22|            7|
+-------+--------------+----+-------------+
```

Thank you for you support.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use [collect_set](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#collect_set(columnName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function to get a set of registers within sequence and use it to derive a "sequence within the sequence" column, which changes on register change.

```sql
SELECT recType, registerNumber, mnId, sequence,
       collect_set(registerNumber) over (partition by sequence order by mnId) as registerSet,
       size(collect_set(registerNumber) over (partition by sequence order by mnId)) as seqInSeq
  FROM dataframe
 ORDER BY mnId;

+-------+--------------+----+--------+--------------------+--------+
|recType|registerNumber|mnId|sequence|registerSet         |seqInSeq|
+-------+--------------+----+--------+--------------------+--------+
|1      |13578000      |0   |1       |[13578000]          |1       |
|11     |13578000      |1   |1       |[13578000]          |1       |
|13     |13578000      |2   |1       |[13578000]          |1       |
|14     |13578000      |3   |1       |[13578000]          |1       |
|14     |13578000      |4   |1       |[13578000]          |1       |
|1      |11121000      |5   |2       |[11121000]          |1       |
|11     |11121000      |6   |2       |[11121000]          |1       |
|13     |11121000      |7   |2       |[11121000]          |1       |
|14     |11121000      |8   |2       |[11121000]          |1       |
|1      |OC387000      |9   |3       |[OC387000]          |1       |
|11     |OC387000      |10  |3       |[OC387000]          |1       |
|13     |OC387000      |11  |3       |[OC387000]          |1       |
|1      |11121000      |12  |4       |[11121000]          |1       |
|11     |11121000      |13  |4       |[11121000]          |1       |
|13     |11121000      |14  |4       |[11121000]          |1       |
|14     |11121000      |15  |4       |[11121000]          |1       |
|11     |OC321000      |16  |4       |[OC321000, 11121000]|2       |
|13     |OC321000      |17  |4       |[OC321000, 11121000]|2       |
|1      |OC322000      |18  |5       |[OC322000]          |1       |
|11     |OC322000      |19  |5       |[OC322000]          |1       |
|13     |OC322000      |20  |5       |[OC322000]          |1       |
|11     |SO352000      |21  |5       |[OC322000, SO352000]|2       |
|13     |SO352000      |22  |5       |[OC322000, SO352000]|2       |
+-------+--------------+----+--------+--------------------+--------+
```

From here `sequence`+`seqInSeq` directly determine groups and it's fairly easy to renumber them using [dense_rank](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#dense_rank():org.apache.spark.sql.Column), we just need to be careful with ordering - we're not numbering from scratch, but only adding extra sequence numbers for rows with `seqInSeq > 1`. This is ensured by `order by seqInSeq != 1`.

```sql
SELECT recType, registerNumber, mnId, dense_rank() over (order by seqInSeq != 1, sequence, seqInSeq) as sequence
  FROM (SELECT recType, registerNumber, mnId, sequence,
            collect_set(registerNumber) over (partition by sequence order by mnId) as registerSet,
            size(collect_set(registerNumber) over (partition by sequence order by mnId)) as seqInSeq
        FROM dataframe)
 ORDER BY mnId;

+-------+--------------+----+--------+
|recType|registerNumber|mnId|sequence|
+-------+--------------+----+--------+
|1      |13578000      |0   |1       |
|11     |13578000      |1   |1       |
|13     |13578000      |2   |1       |
|14     |13578000      |3   |1       |
|14     |13578000      |4   |1       |
|1      |11121000      |5   |2       |
|11     |11121000      |6   |2       |
|13     |11121000      |7   |2       |
|14     |11121000      |8   |2       |
|1      |OC387000      |9   |3       |
|11     |OC387000      |10  |3       |
|13     |OC387000      |11  |3       |
|1      |11121000      |12  |4       |
|11     |11121000      |13  |4       |
|13     |11121000      |14  |4       |
|14     |11121000      |15  |4       |
|11     |OC321000      |16  |6       |
|13     |OC321000      |17  |6       |
|1      |OC322000      |18  |5       |
|11     |OC322000      |19  |5       |
|13     |OC322000      |20  |5       |
|11     |SO352000      |21  |7       |
|13     |SO352000      |22  |7       |
+-------+--------------+----+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you @kombajn for quick response. My requirement is such, if the ```registerNumber``` starts with ```SO3``` or ```OC3```, we need to go for ```collect_set```. I will add that part in the code. Thank you